# Improving performance of Parallel.For in C# with more methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

Recently I've stumbled upon a Parralel.For loop that performs way better than a regular for loop for my purposes.

This is how I use it:

```
Parallel.For(0, values.Count, i =>Products.Add(GetAllProductByID(values[i])));
```

It made my application work a lot faster, but still not fast enough. My question to you guys is:

1. Does Parallel.Foreach performs faster than Parallel.For?
2. Is there some "hybrid" method with whom I can combine my Parralel.For loop to perform even faster (i.e. use more CPU power)? If yes, how?

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `Products.Add` can well be *dangerous* in case `Products` is `List<T>` which is *not* thread safe.

Comment: Do you even have a CPU bottleneck? Have you profiled your code to see what is taking the most time in your program?

Comment: I doubt they work differently in any way that will help you.  Are you certain your process is CPU-bound and not I/O bound?  Could you not pass all IDs into one query to get all data back in one I/O operation?

Comment: Also, how fast is "fast enough"? How many IDs are you sending and what are your performance expectations?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "not thread safe" ? 

Missile, No CPU bottleneck, I've deployed the application onto the host to see how well will it perform, it takes about 5-15 seconds to fetch all the products from query... 

Stanley, No the API I'm using has only the action which takes 1 id at a time and returns a result... I'm using the eBay API to fetch some data from there by passing an product ID ....

Comment: @DStanley Well I'm calling eBay API method (API Call) to fetch 1 product at a time, this is the only function they have to fetch data from product when  I send an ID to the API. Fast enough would be any where between 1-5 seconds that I get a response from API and display the results to my screen...

Comment: @DStanley I send 100 ID's at a time ... The Products list can contain max 100 products at a time ... Currently the app takes anywhere between 5-20 seconds to display the data (depending how much data is there to be returned)... I'd like to lower it down to 1-8 seconds max. Possibly even make 100 API calls all at once??

Comment: `List<T>` is *not* thread safe which means that you *can* (not necessary *must*) have corrupted results (e.g. partially added items, range check errors etc.).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Aha I understand, what would you suggest that I do? Is there an alternative to fix this ? :/

Comment: If you're calling an eBay API, then almost certainly the bottleneck will be the network between you and them, rather than your CPU.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko What other generic collection can I use which is thread safe??

Comment: You _could_ make your UI asynchronous and just add items as you get them back.  That would make it _seem_ faster even though it wouldn't be faster in reality.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes you have a very good point there. :) The thing that I'm trying to achieve (if it's possible) is to make 100 eBay API calls all at once (again if possible).

Comment: @DStanley can you show me what do you mean by that ? :)

Comment: Also bear in mind that these sorts of APIs are usually rate limited in some fashion - if you try to access too many things in too short a space, be prepared for your access to be limited.

Comment: @User987 Not how to implement it, but I'm thinking of sites that add content after the initial page is rendered.  It still takes several seconds to get all of the content, but you get _something_ back sooner, so it doesn't feel as slow because you're not waiting on the _entire page_ to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *play* with parallel, I suggest using *Parallel Linq* (*PLinq*) instead of `Parallel.For` / `Parallel.ForEach` , e.g.

```
 var Products = Enumerable
   .Range(0, values.Count)
   .AsParallel()
   //.WithDegreeOfParallelism(10) // <- if you want, say 10 threads
   .Select(i => GetAllProductByID(values[i]))
   .ToList(); // <- this is thread safe now
```

With a help of `With` methods (e.g. `WithDegreeOfParallelism`) you can try tuning you implementation.

Comment: Let's put this into the perspective of the eBay API calls that I'm doing.  if I set 10 threads, does that means 10 calls will be made at once on 10 thraeds. Or can I perform more than 10 calls on 1 thread if that value is set on 10? :D

Comment: @User987: all 10 threads will be taken from then so called *thread pull*. 10 threads mean that when solving the task up to 10 threads will be used (it will be less than 10 threads if you have less than 10 items to perform). Sure, you can have more than 10 items.

Comment: Holy hell man, you're a genius!!! Not only does this method works at least 2 times faster than my current Parralel.For loop... It's now thread safe as well!!! I just measured the time needed to get the results using my old method, approximately 44 seconds for huge data. With your code it takes < 20 seconds to get results. You're a genius!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

There are two related concepts: asynchronous programming and multithreading. Basically, to do things "in parallel" or asynchronously, you can either create new threads or work asynchronously on the same thread.

Keep in mind that either way you'll need some mechanism to prevent [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). From the Wikipedia article I linked to, a race condition is defined as follows:

> A race condition or race hazard is the behavior of an electronic,
>   software or other system where the output is dependent on the sequence
>   or timing of other uncontrollable events. It becomes a bug when events
>   do not happen in the order the programmer intended.

As a few people have mentioned in the comments, you can't rely on the standard List class to be thread-safe - i.e. it might behave in unexpected ways if you're updating it from multiple threads. Microsoft now offers special "built-in" collection classes (in the [System.Collections.Concurrent namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)) that'll behave in the expected way if you're updating it asynchronously or from multiple threads.

For well-documented libraries (and Microsoft's generally pretty good about this in their documentation), the documentation will often explicitly state whether the class or method in question is thread-safe. For example, in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for System.Collections.Generic.List, it states the following:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

In terms of asynchronous programming (vs. multithreading), my standard illustration of this is as follows: suppose you go a restaurant with 10 people. When the waiter comes by, the first person he asks for his order isn't ready; however, the other 9 people are. Thus, the waiter asks the other 9 people for their orders and then comes back to the original guy. (It's definitely not the case that they'll get a second waiter to wait for the original guy to be ready to order and doing so probably wouldn't save much time anyway). That's how async/await typically works (the exception being that some of the Task Parallel library calls, like Thread.Run(...), actually are executing on other threads - in our illustration, bringing in a second waiter - so make sure you check the documentation for which is which).

Basically, which you choose (asynchronously on the same thread or creating new threads) depends on whether you're trying to do something that's I/O-bound (i.e. you're just waiting for an operation to complete or for a result) or CPU-bound.

If your main purpose is to wait for a result from Ebay, it would probably be better to work asynchronously in the same thread as you may not get much of a performance benefit for using multithreading. Think back to our analogy: bringing in a second waiter just to wait for the first guy to be ready to order isn't necessarily any better than just having the waiter to come back to him.

I'm not sitting in front of an IDE so forgive me if this syntax isn't perfect, but here's an approximate idea of what you can do:

```
public async Task GetResults(int[] productIDsToGet) {
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (int productID in productIDsToGet) {
       Task task = GetResultFromEbay(productID);
       tasks.Add(task);
    }

    // Wait for all of the tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task GetResultFromEbay(int productIdToGet) {
    // Get result asynchronously from eBay
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try you solution :)